# Retrieve expiration date for tiktok video

Tags: curl, request, header, expires-header

I got a tiktok video direct URL that I would like to analyze and retrieve its expiration date.

After analyzing its headers, I found some interesting data, but Im unable to find out its expiration date.

I suspect that parameter "l" includes it, but still, I cannot find a way to decode its value.

Here is my link: https://v19.muscdn.com/4d81640c40c01d29f24dfd60c1ee051e/5e945c1a/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c003/0dc9964505df43288febb6aac33ac6a0/?a=1233&br=472&bt=236&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=3&er=&l=2020041306331401018907221826201EE5&lr=tiktok_m&qs=0&rc=M3Vna3N1d3FrczMzOzczM0ApO2Q6NjZnOzs0N2k7aGhpaGcxaDM0ay1gMHBfLS0wMTZzc182MWI1YzEtYTY2LWNjXzU6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=

And here's its response headers:

```
Request URL: https://v19.muscdn.com/4d81640c40c01d29f24dfd60c1ee051e/5e945c1a/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c003/0dc9964505df43288febb6aac33ac6a0/?a=1233&br=472&bt=236&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=3&er=&l=2020041306331401018907221826201EE5&lr=tiktok_m&qs=0&rc=M3Vna3N1d3FrczMzOzczM0ApO2Q6NjZnOzs0N2k7aGhpaGcxaDM0ay1gMHBfLS0wMTZzc182MWI1YzEtYTY2LWNjXzU6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 206 Partial Content
Remote Address: 151.101.114.113:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Age: 1776148
BD-Request-Id: 3742410735cb7e2560d0de6c0b9855c3
Bd-Status: TCP_HIT
Cache-Control: max-age=15552000
Content-Length: 484481
content-type: video/mp4
Date: Mon, 13 Apr 2020 09:09:32 GMT
Expires: Sat, 19 Sep 2020 19:47:05 GMT
Fastly-Restarts: 1
Last-Modified: Mon, 23 Mar 2020 19:45:52 GMT
server-timing: inner; dur=92
server-timing: cdn-cache;desc=hit, edge;dur=0
Via: http/1.1 10.189.16.66 (bdcache [cHs f ]), cache17.va
Via: 1.1 varnish
Via: 1.1 varnish
X-Cache: HIT, HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 1, 0
X-Served-By: cache-dca17722-DCA, cache-hhn4028-HHN
X-Storagegw-Request-Id: 202003231947050100990191790D040922
X-Storagegw-Response-Time: Mon, 23 Mar 2020 19:47:05 GMT
X-Timer: S1586768973.627470,VS0,VE0
x-tt-trace-tag: id=19;cdn-cache=hit;type=static
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,el-GR;q=0.9,el;q=0.8
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Host: v19.muscdn.com
If-Range: Mon, 23 Mar 2020 19:45:52 GMT
Range: bytes=0-294911
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36
a: 1233
br: 472
bt: 236
cr: 0
cs: 0
dr: 0
ds: 3
er: 
l: 2020041306331401018907221826201EE5
lr: tiktok_m
qs: 0
rc: M3Vna3N1d3FrczMzOzczM0ApO2Q6NjZnOzs0N2k7aGhpaGcxaDM0ay1gMHBfLS0wMTZzc182MWI1YzEtYTY2LWNjXzU6Yw==
vl: 
vr:
```

Answer (score 2):

In the url, notice the second path parameter: `5e945c1a`

```
https://v19.muscdn.com/4d81640c40c01d29f24dfd60c1ee051e/5e945c1a/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c003/0dc9964505df43288febb6aac33ac6a0/?a=1233&br=472&bt=236&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=3&er=&l=2020041306331401018907221826201EE5&lr=tiktok_m&qs=0&rc=M3Vna3N1d3FrczMzOzczM0ApO2Q6NjZnOzs0N2k7aGhpaGcxaDM0ay1gMHBfLS0wMTZzc182MWI1YzEtYTY2LWNjXzU6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=
```

This is the hex value of the expiry date. So in js, and easy way to get the expiry date of the URL will be:

```js
function getExpiry(url) {
    const hex = new URL(url).pathname.split('/')[2];
    return new Date(parseInt(hex, 16) * 1000);
}

const url = 'https://v19.muscdn.com/4d81640c40c01d29f24dfd60c1ee051e/5e945c1a/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c003/0dc9964505df43288febb6aac33ac6a0';

const expiryDate = getExpiry(url);
console.log(expiryDate);
```

However, note that you cannot just change the expiry date and make the URL work for longer. The first path parameter `4d81640c40c01d29f24dfd60c1ee051e` is a hash value that invalidates any change in the URL (except query params). I have not been able to fetch any link for permanent video URL yet.

But I guess this answers your question, since you only asked to know the expiry date.